# Bootstrap Navbar toogle not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap in my WordPress theme to make it responsive.

My menu collapses correctly however my toggle greys out and I can't click it.

I know my scripts are enqueuing correctly as I can see them when I view the source, can anyone see why from my code?

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
         <h2 class="brand">LEAVE YOU</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class=" collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#example1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#example2">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#example3">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: What jquery library are you loading aside from bootstraps .js?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest moving the `<nav>` outside of `<div id="tabs" class="tabs">`. However, all you should need to make it work is to have jQuery, Bootstrap CSS, and Bootstrap JavaScript linked.

If you don't have any of them, you can add the following to your website in the `<head>` tag.

jQuery: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Bootstrap CSS: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Bootstrap JavaScript: `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`